# Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and periodic function. Then which of the following are correct?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and periodic function. Then,

(a) $f$ attains its supremum

(b) $f$ need not be bounded

(c) There doesnot exist sequence $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$ but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\nrightarrow 0$

(d) If $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, then $(f(x_n))$ is also a cauchy sequence.

> My attempt:

I know that $f(x)$ has to be bounded, if it's unbounded then because the function is periodic, it won't be continuous at that point where it goes to $\pm \infty$. Example, $\tan x$ is a function. Hence, (b) is incorrect.

I cannot think how to verify about the other options, please help me. I am not clear about how should I proceed.

Comment: And I thought that (b) was true....

Comment: But then continuity would not be justified, right ? The example that came to my mind was $\tan x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of hints/suggestions to get you started. If a function $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous and periodic, then it means it "repeats itself". So really, you just have to study the behaviour of the function on a compact interval $[\alpha, \alpha + T]$, where $T$ is the period.

Now, since $f: [\alpha, \alpha + T] \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous, it will in fact be uniformly continuous. So, what can you say about the other properties?

---

For example, keep the simple function $\sin(x)$ in mind. All the properties you need to know about it can be understood as long as you understand its behaviour on the interval $[0, 2 \pi]$, because beyond that, the function just repeats itself. So, if you want to know about boundedness, continuity, differentiability (at points of the open interval of periodicity) etc it suffices to consider just that interval

Comment: So, since function is uniformly continuous, options (c),(d) clearly hold. Also $[a,a+T]$ being compact function will attain its supremum (and infimum). How do you justify (b) ?

Comment: @s1mple well, if you manage to prove that continuous on $\Bbb{R}$ and periodic implies uniform continuity on all of $\Bbb{R}$ (not just on the compact interval), then yes (c) and (d) are straightforward. Also, because (a) is true, (b) has to be false (it's a one/two line proof).

Comment: Yes, thanks. Since infimum and supremum exists it would have to be bounded.

Comment: @s1mple yes exactly